# How to align chapter, section, subsection with parindent?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

Is there a way to solve that?

[image: ?]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible; the section number is typeset by the macro `\@seccntformat` and it's just a matter of giving it a suitable redefinition: typeset the number in a fixed width box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \protect\makebox[\parindent][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

\setlength\parindent{2.5pc}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}

\subsection{Aliquam vestibulum}

\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection{Aliquam vestibulum}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

When `minitoc` is loaded (which I don't recommend, I find it distracting and not really useful), a bizarre thing happens: the package unfortunately redefines a key macro without using `\@seccntformat`, which is utterly wrong. You can patch it, though, restoring the correct behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \patchcmd
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \protect\makebox[2.5pc][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
% patch the wrong definition of `\stc@sect`
\patchcmd{\stc@sect}
  {\edef\@svsec{\csname the#1\endcsname\hskip1em}}
  {\protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\setlength\parindent{2.5pc}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}

\subsection{Aliquam vestibulum}

\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection{Aliquam vestibulum}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Awesome answer! This community is amazing!

Comment: @aYk6jhH2SFGd You're welcome!

Comment: Why \usepackage{minitoc} disarrange it?

Comment: @aYk6jhH2SFGd Because `minitoc` is badly written, unfortunately. I added a patch.

Comment: @egreg: `minitoc`'s also (i think) the largest single latex package on ctan.  it incorporates a lengthy essay (with maps and flags included) about (i suppose) tocs.  i'd sort of vaguely thought of negotiating "inheriting" it from drucbert, but i've never quite had the necessary effort available.

Comment: @wasteofspace I'm afraid to have heard that Jean-Pierre F. Drucbert passed away.

Comment: most, if not all, of `minitoc`'s features can be replicated using `titletoc`