# Absolute ident of section heading text but not number

Tags: sectioning, formatting, margins, tabbing

I'd like to (resp. have to) ident the text of all section headings in a document (+ the abstract and quote enviornments, but that should be easy--by comparison) to 0.4" from the left margin of the page (like using a tab in a word processor).

The headings should look like this:

[image: Absolute positioning of section title from left margin.]

So far, I have:

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
```

My guess is that there should be a way to replace \quad with something that works like a \absoluteposition or \tabto? Is there any onboard way to do this in Latex

I'm also using the sectsty package for some other reason but couldn't find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: You could use something like `\def\@seccntformat#1{\makebox[2cm][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}}`, but I'm sure we already have a question like this. Maybe someone can find it.

Comment: Found: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169567/how-to-align-chapter-section-subsection-with-parindent and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26905/fix-indent-for-section-title

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: [How to align chapter, section, subsection with parindent?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169567/how-to-align-chapter-section-subsection-with-parindent)

Thanks everyone for helping out, for whatever reason I was unable to use the proper search terms in order to find this.